# Buffering question in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, memcached

I'd like to know how to configure Microsoft SQL Server to work in the following manner:

- All db writes are "write behind", all of the queries operate primarily out of the RAM cache (for speed), i.e. it persists the data to the hard drive at its leisure, in the background.

The reason? Speed. We assume 99.99% reliability of the underlying machine (its an Amazon EC2 instance), so we don't mind caching all of the data in RAM (and even if there is a failure we can just rebuild the database ourselves anyway from 3rd party data sources).

For example:

- User 1 writes data packet X to the database.
- User 2 queries this same data packet X, 2ms later.
- User 2 should see data packet X, as SQL will serve it straight out of its RAM cache (even if data packet X hasn't been persisted to the hard drive).
- Data packet X will be persisted to the hard drive at leisure, maybe 500ms later.

Comment: Questions about how to setup and configure SQL Server, or how to run it in production, are best asked at [ServerFault.com](http://serverfault.com) where the sysadmins and SQL DBA's hang out. This here is a site for **programming-related** questions

Comment: I'd like to know the T-SQL programming code to configure this.

Comment: Does this really relate to memcached?

Comment: it's stil a server configuration, not a programming, question. The cache should be *transparent* to your programs. You yourself want to know "how to configure".

Comment: I guess I can work out the T-SQL code to configure this from within my program, once I know the configuration options. How do I move the question to serverfault.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have large amounts of memory and have set a high Min Memory setting in your SQL Server instance than SQL will attempt to maximize its use.

The Checkpoint process is the thing which forces the dirty pages to be written to disk (which happens automatically but can be forced) so you might want to have a read of the following.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188748.aspx

This subject is quite involved and can be effected by the hardware and solution you are using. For instance Virtualization brings a whole ream of other considerations.

Comment: Perfect answer - all I have to do is set the CheckPoint value to something befitting an extremely reliable system such as Amazon EC2: perhaps 30 seconds.